# GET call to a Google API responds with "Unauthorized"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpclient

**UPDATE: Figured this out.  I DID need to add the authorization header as answered below but I also believe the issue for my particular use case is that the access token (which I verified through Postman) required more scopes to authenticate me fully, which makes sense since this API contains surveys that I am trying to access, which are also linked to a Google account. Once I added the extra scopes needed to access the surveys to the token request along with the authorization header code below I was able to connect successfully.**

**More info on adding scopes to C# code can be found here: http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/**

**Hope this helps anyone running into similar issues. Thanks all!**

I am trying to make a GET call to a Google API but it keeps responding with "Unauthorized" while I am logged in to Gmail. I've already implemented Google+ Sign-In in StartUp.Auth.cs and even saved the access token for later use.

So how do I get the HttpClient to authorize me?

I have an access token available but I do not know how to pass it in properly.  I've seen examples with usernames and passwords, but I should not need to pass those parameters if I already have an access token?  If anything, I should be able to have the user redirected to a login page instead if needed when I log out before running the solution.

What I am expecting when the project is run, is the result of the GET call to come back in the form of json but it always says I'm "Unauthorized" and I am probably missing 1 line of code somewhere...

Here is the code I am using:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    string _url = "https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys?key={MY_API_KEY}";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                var Content = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewBag.GoogleResponse = Content.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // THIS IS ALWAYS UNAUTHORIZED!
            ViewBag.GoogleResponse = response.StatusCode + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help with ideas or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xxx");` where xxx is your token

Comment: If you're obtaining a token as per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 then I would've said that should work. Does the scope which the token is authorised for extend to the operation you are trying to do? Is ViewBag.GoogleAccessToken definitely populated?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the token which prints out on the page render, and it is set before the GET call is made.  You have the same answer as someone else though, so I will try messing with it a bit more and report on what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I think you mean they made the same answer as me ;)

Comment: i am getting invalid_token but this doesnt make sense as the token was JUST created!  I opened a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403172/c-sharp-mvc-google-apis-why-is-this-access-token-invalid-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the auth token in an `Authorization` Header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Comment: Didn't work, but you have the same answer as someone else so I will try messing with it a bit more and report on what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: can you try making the request in Fiddler, curl, Postman etc so that you can make sure the request work as you would expect regardless of your HttpClient code?

Comment: I am logged into Gmail and the Postman GET call to  https://www.someurl.com?key={MY_API_KEY} returns this: {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}

Comment: i am getting invalid_token but this doesnt make sense as the token was JUST created!  I opened a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403172/c-sharp-mvc-google-apis-why-is-this-access-token-invalid-instantly

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever gotten an response for this api/survey?  If you were unable to get a response from the API by hitting it with Postman, you may have issues in the way you are targeting the API.  The error being returned there seems like you weren't including the token in your request header.  Did you click the Authorization tab below the request URL to add the OAuth token to your header?  (Keep in mind that the {} characters need to be URL encoded)

Also, when you are referencing MY_API_KEY, is that analagous to your surveyId?

I don't have a lot of experience here, but I have a couple of suggestions :

1) I agree with Pedro, you definitely need to include the Authorization Header in your request.

2) If your MY_API_KEY is in fact the survey ID, you may be providing an incorrect URL (GoogleAPIs documentation indicates that it should be < http://www.googleapis.com/consumer-surveys/v2/surveys/***surveyId*** >

Recommendation (after moving your API key to a string var named MY_API_KEY) :

```
string _url = "https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys/";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ViewBag.GoogleAccessToken);

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(MY_API_KEY).Result)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            var Content = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ViewBag.GoogleResponse = Content.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Reference:

```
 https://developers.google.com/consumer-surveys/v2/reference/
 http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions! When I did #2 it said "Cannot implicitly convert Task<HttpResponseMessage> to HttpResponseMessage. For #3, MY_API_KEY is the api key for my oauth 2.0 client ID on the google developer console.  Is that the wrong info?

Comment: On Postman I typed in http://https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys?key=MY_API_KEY and see "Unauthorized".  (I'm new to Postman and need to find a good guide). But anyway, before I get to specifying what survey ID i want to look up (I was really trying to get a list of the ones I've created first) what I really need to figure out is why I can't get past this "Unauthorized" part first, unless they are fully connected?

Comment: You shouldn't need to put the client ID into URL string as a parameter.  Once you authorize correctly, you should be able to execute a GET request with the OAuth token against the https://www.googleapis.com/consumerserveys/v2/surveys url, and it should return the surveys associated with the authorized client.

(I removed part 2 re: using directive since it was not helpful)

Comment: When you access Postman, you need to make sure that your OAuth token is in the header data.  Let Postman generate this for you :

1) Open Postman and add the target URL : https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys
2) Click the "Authorization" tab, select OAuth 2.0 from the drop down, and fill out the necessary details - click Request Token
3) After Authorization information is added to the header, make sure you have GET selected and try to send again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I have made some progress with being able to verify that the API does respond with the survey list in Postman, however I cannot get the access tokens to work outside of the ones generated from OAuth2.0 Playground.  The ones I generate in Postman do not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407333/why-do-only-oauth-2-0-playground-access-tokens-work-for-google-api